# Как в Woocommerce добавить поле к названию в карточке товара?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Необходимо добавить поле как на скриншоте выделено красным.
 Возможно ли добавить поля через произвольные поля в wordpress или необходимо использовать плагины ? 
Какие есть возможные варианты добавления? 
Спасибо за ответы
[image: дополнительное поле для товара в woocommerce]

Comment: Ну насколько я понял, на скрине это категория товара. Также можно использовать доп. поля с помощью плагина ACF

Comment: Не совсем, это я добавил что бы более понятно было, например если бы там была модель или серийный номер

Comment: @AndrewKozhemyakin можете галочкой отметить ответ, чтобы принять его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем поле:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'my_product_fields');
function my_product_fields() {
    $args = [
        'id'    => 'my_field',
        'label' => __( 'My field name', 'plugin-name' ),
    ];
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
```

Сохраняем поле:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'my_save_fields' );
function my_save_fields( $post_id ) {
    $product   = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $instagram = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'my_field', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );
    $product->update_meta_data( 'my_field', sanitize_text_field( $instagram ) );
    $product->save();
}
```

Выводим поле:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'my_field_on_loop_show', 2 );
function my_field_on_loop_show() {
    global $product;
    echo $product->get_meta( 'my_field' );
}
```